# HttpListenerContext adds "%EF%BF%BD" recursive to HttpListener.request.url

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, network-programming, httplistener

In my application I have a `HttpListener listener` running constantly in the background on a seperate thread. This listener is used to process files that get requested over a localhost port. And requests said files from the server.

The listener is set up as follows

```
listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://+:50003/");
listener.Start();
httpListenerThread = new Thread(RunListener);
httpListenerThread.Start();
```

It's kept alive on the thread using

```
while (listenerIsRunning)
{
    if (listener.IsListening)
    {
         IAsyncResult result = listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(HttpRequestListenerCallback), listener);
         result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(1);
    }
}
```

and if a file gets requested over the HttpListener I get the requested file name in the callback like this (where `result` is of type `IAsyncResult` containing `object state`):

```
 HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)result.AsyncState;
 HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result);
 string fileName = context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Substring(1);
```

This works fine most of the time. Returning the filename that has been requested as expected. But occasionally (and inconsistently) it will append "%EF%BF%BD" 104 times to the filename, and "GP" to close it off.. looking like this

"%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD .... %EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BDGP"

It doesn't happen to the same file everytime either. And a file that it happened to can be requested just fine on a new iteration.

Checking the name of the file before it gets send to the HttpListener yields just the filename, meaning it gets added somewhere during the process off the `HttpListener`, or `HttpListenerContext`.

Everything is/should be done using the ASCII charset.

I am using Unity's .Net 2.0 subset with .net 3.5 equivalent runtime version

Comment: TCP messages can get combined and split by routes and server according to the specification.  So sometimes when two message are sent they get combined into a single received message.  So with text usually you add a CR (or other terminator) at end of each message so the receive know where each message ends.  With binary data you must add a byte count at beginning of message to indicate where the end is.  You can also use Fixed Length messages to determine the end of a message.

Comment: So if I'm understanding you correctly it is partial data from the next message being mixed in? And adding a terminator to the end of the requested filename should fix this as the receiver knows where the message ended?

Comment: @jdweng is talking about TCP messages, but HTTP abstracts all of that away so that remark is irrelevant. If .NET's HttpListener (which is based on the [Windows HTTP Server API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/http/using-http-server-api)) would have such bugs, you wouldn't be the first to notice.

Comment: Anyway who is sending requests to your listener? Do you control that code?

Comment: You need to add the proper code to the receiver to check if you have a terminator (or multiple terminators) and parse the receive data appropriately.  You also have to be careful where you set the WaitOne so the main thread is synchronized with the Async Method.  If the Asyn method raises the WaitOne once when two messages are received then the main thread has to process all the received messages in the queue.  I usually create a FIFO (implemented with a List) and have the Async add all the incoming data to list and raise 
WaitOne,  Then have main thread read all items in the FIFO.

Comment: @CoadeCaster : Only if you are using http1.0 in stream mode and you get a 200 Done.  What happens if you do not get 200 Done or you are in chunk mode http1.1?

Comment: @codeCaster The requests are send by a mediaplayer that is requesting HLS files (.m3u8/.ts files). I am controlling that code and logging its requests, which yields the clean filename (e.g BigBuckBunny.m3u8)

Comment: @jdweng HttpListener handles that for you. If you call `EndGetContext()`, you'll have a complete HTTP request. The OP is not implementing an HTTP server using sockets themselves.

Comment: @remy and where are those clients? Behind weird proxies perhaps?

Comment: Even in Async Mode?

Comment: Unsure what you mean wtih "where are those clients". But currently testing with both a hosted server, and running the server on localhost, both having the same results where everything works fine only 9/10 times. Testing from both desktop (unity editor)  and from mobile devices running a development build. 

Not using a proxy on any of the devices.

Comment: Well either your input is garbage, or someone in the middle (e.g. a proxy server) adds garbage. The character sequence you show is the Unicode replacement character for unrepresentable code points. Perhaps the way you read your playlists is incorrect, and you fail to log the requested filenames correctly (did you try adding quotes around it before logging?). The HttpListener doesn't add random characters to the request URI.